# Inputing Integers error throwing

Tags: java, input, error-handling, integer, try-catch

Can someone help me make this code neater. I would rather use parse int than a buffer reader. I want my code to loop until the user inputs a number. I couldn't figure out how to do this without the code printing out the same statement twice.

```
public void setAge() 
{
    try {
        age = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("What is your age?");
        this.setAge();
    }
}
```

**Alright, my question is unclear. I am unsure of how to handle the error that a scanner throws when you don't input an integer. How do I handle this? I found "NumberFormatException" in a different post, but I am unsure of what this does. Can anyone help me with this, or is my question still unclear?**

Comment: If you use `nextInt` method of `Scanner`and the input isn't a int, it will throw a `InputMismatchException`. Check my answer and see if that's what you needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestScanner {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = null;
    int age = -1;
    do {
      try {
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is your age?");
        age = scanner.nextInt();
      } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number!");
      }
    } while (age == -1);
    System.out.println("You are " + age + " years old.");

    if (scanner != null)
      scanner.close();
  }

}
```

I get this output (the first time I enter abc instead of a number to make it retry):

```
What is your age?
abc
Please enter a number!
What is your age?
35
You are 35 years old.
```

Have fun!

Comment: Fantastic! I always appreciate complete, working code examples, so I try to provide them in my answers as well. Glad you found this useful!

Comment: I have one question for you. I have not ever written an if statement to check if a scanner is null. What is this for, and what is the purpose of scanner.close()?

Comment: It's probably not necessary in this case, but this is a coding idiom I've gotten in the habit of using for resources like Scanners. The close() is to prevent a resource leak, though it's not necessary for this simple program because when main terminates, the entire program goes out of scope, but it's a good programming habit to close() all resources in this fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Use `scan.nextInt();` instead of `scan.nextLine();`

With this, you don't need to parse the line.

EDIT: Oops, i misread your question

Comment: what is nestLine() ??

Comment: Do you know how to handle the error that this throws?

Comment: @JohnFriedrich what number you entered ?

Comment: You can us Use `Scanner.hasNextInt()`
 `while (!scan.hasNextInt()) scan.next();
    int age = scan.nextInt();`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a scanner.
You'll need to;

```
import java.util.*;

static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
```

You won't need the parse statement at all.

```
age = console.nextInt();
```

EDIT: Editing my answer after seeing your edit.

I would put the entire try in a do loop. Using a new boolean variable to control when you come out of it.

```
boolean excep;

do {
excep = false;
try {
age = console.nextInt();
}
catch (Exception exRef) {
System.out.println("Please input an integer");
console.nextLine();
excep = true; 
}
} while (excep);
```

The console.nextLine() just clears a line so it doesnt re-read the last input. Sometimes it's needed.
Using this i don't receive any error notifications on the running of it.

Answer (score 1):

Number Format Exception occurs in the java code when a programmer tries to convert a String into a number. The Number might be int,float or any java numeric values.

The conversions are done by the functions Integer.parseInt.Consider if you give the value of str is "saurabh", the function call will fail to compile because "saurabh" is not a legal string representation of an int value and NumberFormatException will occurs

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
static boolean firstTime = true;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean firstTime = true;
    setAge();
}

public static void setAge() 
{
    if(firstTime)
    {
        System.out.println("What is your age?");
        firstTime = false;
    }

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    try{
        int age = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println(age);
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException e)
    {
        setAge();
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to print different messages you would have to do like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Numbers {

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Numbers numbers = new Numbers();
    numbers.setAge();
}

private boolean alrearyAsked = false;
private int age = 0;
static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
public void setAge() 
{
    try {
        age = scan.nextInt();
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        if (alrearyAsked) {
            System.out.println("you typed a wrong age, please try again.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("What is your age?");
        }
        this.setAge();
    }
}
```

}